Google Credential Manager getId() Method Returns Google ID Instead of Email Address for Gmail Account
I am using Google Credential Manager in my Android app to handle sign-in with Google accounts. I successfully implemented the feature, but I’m encountering an issue when logging in with a specific test Gmail account.
For my personal Gmail account, the credential.getId() method correctly returns the email address (e.g., example@gmail.com). However, when I use my other Gmail account, credential.id returns a Google ID instead of the email address (e.g., 118024214837256241790).
According to the Google Credential Manager documentation, the getId() method should return the email address associated with the Google account.
private val signInWithGoogleOption = GetSignInWithGoogleOption.Builder(serverClientId = SERVER_CLIENT_ID).build()
    
    private suspend fun googleSignIn(
        activity: Activity,
        onSuccess: (GoogleIdTokenCredential) -> Unit
    ) {
        val request = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(signInWithGoogleOption)
            .build()
    
        val result = credentialManager.getCredential(activity, request)
        val credential = result.credential
        Timber.d("Credential ID: ${credential.id}")
    }

The current version of credential manager:
implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials:1.5.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.credentials:credentials-play-services-auth:1.5.0-beta01"

Any advice or suggestions to help resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I would recommended you to get email by sign in idToken, And is not guarantee that credential.id always return email.


    suspend fun googleSignInOAuth(
        context: Context,
        success: (String) -> Unit,
        failure: (String) -> Unit,
    ) {
        try {
            val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

            val hashedNonce = try {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
                val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
                val digest = md.digest(bytes)
                digest.fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }
            } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
                failure("Failed to log in try again")
                return
            }

            val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(context)
            val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
                .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false)
                .setServerClientId("Your server android client id")
                .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
                .setNonce(hashedNonce)
                .build()


            val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
                .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
                .build()

            val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                request = request,
                context = context,
            )
            val credential = result.credential


            val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                .createFrom(credential.data)

            val idToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken

            val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        success(idToken)
                        val email = task.result.user?.photoUrl

                        Log.d(TAG, "Firebase sign in successful")
                        // Handle successful sign-in (e.g., navigate to another activity)
                    } else {
                        failure("Failed to sign in try again")
                        Log.e(TAG, "Firebase sign-in failed: ${task.exception?.localizedMessage}")
                    }
                }


            // Process the Google ID token credential as needed
        } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
            failure("Failed to log in try again")
            Log.e(TAG, "GetCredentialException: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
            failure("Failed to log in try again")
            Log.e(TAG, "GoogleIdTokenParsingException: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Handle network issues, such as no connectivity
            failure("Network error. Please check your internet connection and try again.")
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Handle any other unexpected exceptions
            failure("An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.")
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: ${e.localizedMessage}")
        }

    }


